# Adding a Google Drive video to a sidebar in Google Sheets or Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, html5-video

^^ does not answer the question. also other stackoverflow searches seems to have outdated information on this. maybe it worked at one point, i don't know, but doesn't now.

I want to include instructional videos in google sheets or docs (not sites as I can't edit the doc or sheet directly next to the video) but i want it to be from google drive NOT youtube.

I also know that google forms, slides, and sites allows video embedding so just hoping there is a workaround for sheets (preferably) or docs.

I have added a sidebar:

```
function showSidebar(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("sidebar")
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setWidth(300)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

but none of the ways I can think to include the video work for a drive file. the following works for youtube:

```
 <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
```

the following is what I would think I should be able to use:

```
 <video width="400" autoplay controls>
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/fileID/preview" type="video/mp4">

    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
```

While I see what @ruben is saying- that i can embed the video in the sites- it doesn't really seem to work if i try to then embed the link to sites as an iframe in the subbar in the google sheet.

i've also tried google add ons and aps but haven't found one that works the way i need it to. user doesn't want to have to open new screen.

Comment: If you state **"none of the ways i can think work"**, you should **provide the ways you've tried**, so that you don't get useless "try this way" answers when you've already tried it that way. To me, you're barking up the wrong tree - Google does not intend for Drive to be a server from which you can host rich content for other platforms. This is why there are quota limitations on unique accesses per day, etc.

Comment: tree : There are several threads that could be related to your question. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-drive-sdk%5D+video+embedding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding Google drive videos on a Google Site using Google Apps Script just gives me a Grey Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098572/embedding-google-drive-videos-on-a-google-site-using-google-apps-script-just-giv)

Comment: The HTML Service is the same // It works the same way no matter of the container of it is used to publish a web app.

Comment: thanks. i tried embedding the site page (with the video embedded) as an iframe but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tanaike got me moving in the right direction with using the link:

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=fileID

but I was getting a 403 error. If you are in an organization you may have to use a link like the following link in a browser:

https://drive.google.com/a/yourcompany.com/uc?id=fileid

this link will actually forward you to a new link. This new link is then what you can use to host and play a drive file.

Thanks everyone!

update: there are sharing/permission issues you have to deal with on the file itself so others might not be able to see video. still investigating

update #2- you just have to create the link on the fly as each user will get their own link to view it.

you have to put this in your code.gs file

```
function createLink(){
   var fileId = 'fileID';
   var getFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
    Logger.log(getFile);
   var url = getFile.getDownloadUrl();
    Logger.log(url);


    url = url.replace("&e=download&gd=true","");

    var output = '<video width="400" autoplay controls><source src="'+url+'" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</video>';
    Logger.log(output);

    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output)
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setWidth(600)
  .setTitle("Embedded video");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How much size of video file do you want to use? If the size is small, how about this modification? In my environment, when I add the video in Google Drive using the video tag to the sidebar, I use the webContentLink without `export=download`. (You can also use the webContentLink with `export=download`.) So could you please try to do this modification?

#### From :

```
<video width="400" autoplay controls>
<source src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/fileID/preview" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

#### To :

```
<video width="400" autoplay controls>
<source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=fileID" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

#### Note :

- In this case, when the size of video file is large, the loading time becomes long. Please be careful this.

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: It's exactly what I want but when I try i get a blank spot on the page and copying the link directly into the browser gives me a 403 error.

Comment: @tree does it work for that same file or other known, non-YouTube video files hosted in a dedicated publicly accessible location (i.e. is it unsupported as an element, or is Drive not serving the content you expect?

Comment: @tree I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: @Tanaike hey- you got me on the right track! full code example is below. thanks!!!